# What ec2 image (ami) do you recommend for working with java 5, jboss, mysql, apache?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jboss, amazon-ec2

What ec2 image (ami) do you recommend for working with java 5, jboss, mysql, apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this one](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry!default.jspa?categoryID=116&externalID=1523&fromSearchPage=true), or just install one of the Amazon base Fedora 8 AMIs, install the stack yourself and create your own custom AMI (more flexible).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm paranoid, but I suggest going with well-known providers of AMI images.  To me, it's worth putting in the effort of installing the software you need on a trustworthy system.  I'm not saying there are trojan horses and server-side-spyware all over the place, but think about it: why do you have to install from media after a break-in?  Because even if things seem fine, you can never be sure if you can trust your system.  Like The Oracle says, "know thyself."

These days, I have been enjoying the Ubuntu 8.10 server image (just search for AMIs with the string "canonical").  If you add the universe repo then there is a Sun Java5 package as well as Apache httpd of course.  I'm not sure about JBoss, sorry.